# Have a perforamance issue of query date object using Django queryset

Tags: mysql, django, performance, orm

I'm using django 1.8.4 writing a webapp. The backend uses MySQL 5.6 (MyISAM). Recently the number of table records reaches 1 million, it will take 1-1.5 seconds to query all distinct record dates. But using MySQL client, it takes less than 0.001 second.

**Django Code**

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(db_index=True)

# benchmark code
db_dates = Model1.objects.dates("date", kind="day")
```

**MySQL query:**

```
SELECT date FROM `table1` group by date ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

MySQL client says: 620 total, Query took 0.0025 seconds.

---

### Update 1

Regarding @e4c5 hint, I dumped the django queries. Actually there is a type cast in the query. This is the root cause of the slow.

```
{u'time': u'1.989', 
 u'sql': u"SELECT DISTINCT CAST(DATE_FORMAT(`model1_table`.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AS DATETIME) AS `datefield` FROM `model1_table` WHERE `model1_table`.`date` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `datefield` ASC"}
```

Even I run the queries manually in a MySQL client, it becomes slow. I noticed the second query did a type cast.

Is the type cast (`date` to `datetime`) necessary? How can I solve the problem?

Anyway, I've fired an [issue here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25470#ticket) for tracking.

Comment: did you check what query django is executing?

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks. The query dump indicates, even the query is executed by a MySQL client, it is also slow. Now I'm trying to understand, why django do a DATETIME cast.

Comment: ouch! I am very happy to belong to the school that always stores unix timestamps in the database! Does this also happen with [obj.date for obj in Model1.objects.distinct('date')]

Comment: @e4c5 I tried with your code, it says "DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend". You are very close the solution, please create an answer, so that I can upvote.

Comment: Your ORM statement and your SQL query are not the same. The equivalent ORM query is `Model1.objects.order_by('date').values('date')`

Comment: I haven't unfortunately found the answer myself yet. Where I am at the moment, I can't get my hands on a mysql database. I think @BurhanKhalid has got it. To make it distinct you can perhaps use your original set notation. [obj.date for obj in set(Model1.objects.only('date'))]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Root Cause

Django generates internally such a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  CAST(
    DATE_FORMAT(`model1_table`.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') AS DATETIME
  ) AS `datefield` 
FROM `model1_table` WHERE `model1_table`.`date` IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY `datefield` ASC"
```

Obviously, all DATE fields are first casted to DATETIME and then use its date part. The performance impact is scale to the number of records.

### Solutions

1. As @e4c5 mentioned, we can use

`results = set(obj.date for obj in Model1.objects.distinct('date'))`

But this only works with PostgreSQL. It will not work with MySQL. We will get an error: "*DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend*".

2. @BurhanKhalid 's answer will retrieve all date object to client, which is also slow. I quickly found we can add a `distinct` to filter result from the server side.

Here is my modified version.

`results = set(Model1.objects.order_by('date').values_list('date', flat=True).distinct())`

Now it takes only 0.004 second to query distinct date field from 1.5 million records. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

As MySQL doesn't support DISTINCT ON in the django ORM, you can do it on the client end:

```
set(Model1.objects.order_by('date').values_list('date', flat=True))
```

Comment: This is at least 3 time slower when query a 1.5M records table.

Comment: It will be because you are filtering on the client side and not the db side. Make sure you measure with debug off.

Comment: I made it by adding a distinct to the query. See my answer.